# XML Parsing with Python - find attribute value in XML file

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am working new in Parsing and have an issue which I dont know how to solve.

I have a XML-file (see bellow) and I just want to get the value of the a in preset, which is -1

```
<global>
    <setting lid="diagnosticEcgSpeed"  val="-1" pers="" res="" unit="mm/s">
        <txt id="001041" description="" type="">Geschwindigkeit</txt>
        <value lid="1" val="-1" text="50"/>
        <value lid="2" val="-2" text="25"/>
        <value lid="4" val="-4" text="12,5"/>
        <!-- todo: only one value is needed -> use adult value -->
        <preset i="-1" c="-1" a="-1" />
    </setting>
```

I tried so far this code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('basics.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

x=root.find(".//*[@lid='diagnosticEcgSpeed']/preset").attrib
print(x)
```

and I get:

```
{'i': '-1', 'c': '-1', 'a': '-1'}
```

What do I need to change in my codes so that I get just the value of a and not all attributes in preset?

Comment: Please ask a new question. Do not add extra stuff to an existing question with an answer that you have accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the returned value is a dictionary itself, you can try

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(r"C:\Users\\Downloads\new downloads\temp\abc.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

x=root.find(".//*[@lid='diagnosticEcgSpeed']/preset").attrib['a']
print(x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sakshi ! Exactly what I wanted. I tried so much.

Comment: I have another question. May you can help me.
Now, I would like to get the value of val, which is -1 in the same line as lid="diagnosticEcgSpeed"

I tried this:
x=root.find(".//*[@lid='diagnosticEcgSpeed']").attrib['val']

But it fails

Comment: x=root.find(".//*[@lid='diagnosticEcgSpeed']").attrib['val'] should return the value of 'val' as by passing ".//*[@lid='diagnosticEcgSpeed']" we are geiing the whole dictionary which also contains val as a key in it. {'lid': 'diagnosticEcgSpeed', 'val': '-1', 'pers': '', 'res': '', 'unit': 'mm/s'}

Comment: I tried, but I dont get any return:
for enter: x=root.find(".//*[@lid='diagnosticEcgSpeed']/preset").attrib['a']

return is: KeyError: 'val'

I dont get the attribute of val